Why can permanents and hafnians be viewed as partition functions?
In the description of the book "Combinatorics and Complexity of Partition Functions", by Alexander Barvinok, it is written "...The main focus of the book is on efficient ways to compute (approximate) various partition functions, such as permanents, hafnians and their higher-dimensional versions, graph and hypergraph matching polynomials, the independence polynomial of a graph and partition functions enumerating 0-1 and integer points in polyhedra...".
I can kind of see why permanents and hafnians can be viewed as partition functions, but, as I don't know much about partition functions to be honest, I would like to see the details. Could someone please point me to the literature (I don't currently have access to a library so I cannot at the moment access the book I've mentioned itself)? Or maybe someone could explain why this is so? What are the corresponding physical systems, etc? Thank you.
Edit: in light of Sam Hopkins's comment and a reply I got from A. Barvinok, it seems that the expression "partition function" means different things to different people. I understand now that they mean something specific in enumerative combinatorics, but I guess I would like to understand better how such combinatorial objects arise in physics. A reference suggested to me by prof. Barvinok is the article by Heilmann and Lieb, entitled "The theory of monomer-dimer systems". This is great, but I also wonder if there is a physical interpretation of partition functions in the combinatorial sense in case the weights happen to be complex, for example, rather than non-negative reals.

Essentially by definition, the permanent is a generating function of permutations, and the hafnian is a generating function of perfect matchings. Compared to their classical analogs of determinant and pfaffian, the point is that there are no signs in these generating function expressions. Look up e.g. papers of Kuperberg on the "permanent-determinant"/"hafnian-pfaffian" method.

Hi @SamHopkins, yes I understand your statements. I will look up Kuperberg's articles that you've mentioned. Thank you.
